# Couldn't Iterate The List More in Python 3

Tags: python, web

After several searching and modifies, I still couldn't figure it out.  It stops at the 19th in the list.

This is the error:

```
line 22 in <module> parent_td=[td for td in possible_tds if 'Product' in td.text][0]
Index Error: List index out of range
```

---

```
    from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
    from urllib.request import Request
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
    import re

    ListName = "list"
    OpenList = open(ListName,"r")
    n=int(OpenList.readline())

    for num in range(1,n+1):
         print(num)
         theList=OpenList.readline()

         AccessCME=Request(theList,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
         CMEPage=uReq(AccessCME).read()

         page_soup=soup(CMEPage,"html.parser")
         cme=page_soup.find("div",{"class":"cmeProduct section"})
         FuturesContracts=cme.span.text.strip()

         possible_tds=page_soup.find_all('td',attrs={'class':"prodSpecAtribute"})
         parent_td=[td for td in possible_tds if 'Product' in td.text][0]
         target = parent_td.fetchNextSiblings('td')[0].text.strip()
         first_take=re.sub('CME Globex:\s', '', target)
         BaseSymbol=re.sub(r'CME ClearPort:.*', '', first_take)

         print(FuturesContracts, BaseSymbol)
```

The link is the list file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzzXkoIWuMAHWEhaQktrT3BKdG8/view?usp=sharing

Let me know if I need to clarify anything else. Improvements/suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Looks to me the list comprehension simply did generate an empty list. So there is no `td` in `possible_tds` such that `'Product'` is in `td.text`.

Comment: Hi, Willem, thanks for the explanation. But I'm very new to coding. Could you expand more on what you are saying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not find any candidates in your list comprehension, and end up with an empty list.

```
possible_tds=page_soup.find_all('td',attrs={'class':"prodSpecAtribute"})
parent_td_candidates = [td for td in possible_tds if 'Product' in td.text]
if parent_td_candidates:
    parent_td = parent_td_candidates[0]
    # target = ...
else:
    print('No parent td candidates found! Is my data messed up or do I have a bug?')
```

Comment: Hi, Harri. I thought I got 20 as my upper bound. And There are 20 website links. So I don't know how you knew it is an empty list. Could you expand more on this thought and how to solve it?

Comment: I knew it was an empty list because your Exception told me so. Your program threw "Index Error" on a line where the only index access was index 0. As a result, the length of the list must be 0.

Comment: thank you, Harri. So how can I modify my code to solve it?

Comment: The problem appears to be that one url does not follow the same table format. Check it out for yourself, no CME Globex and Clearport are not located by Product Code Cell: http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/metals/base/copper_contract_specifications.html

Comment: Gotcha! Since there is no **Product code** in **Copper**, Python couldn't iterate! Thank you!